# How to solve render problem in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Am facing an series problem from few days back only. Before that i didn't recieve this error. I can able to build the project but errors are showing only in Layout files alone
Following is error code in layout files:

```
android.view.InflateException: Class not found LinearLayout
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater_Delegate.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater_Delegate.java:63)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater.java:201)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:141)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1402)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1361)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1336)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:360)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:694)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5535)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:996)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:990)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:108)
at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.<init>(MaterialTextView.java:93)
at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.<init>(MaterialTextView.java:88)
at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.<init>(MaterialTextView.java:83)
at com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater.createTextView(MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java:61)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:121)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LinearLayout not found.
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.findClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:899)
at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater_Delegate.inflateFromClass(DrawableInflater_Delegate.java:45)
... 43 more
```

Due to this error my layout is not showing properly.
[image: error screen] Textinputlayouts are not visible properly. Kindly advise me

and my gradle file is

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.zenovic.trust'
    minSdkVersion 28
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.1'
    multiDexEnabled true

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets {
            srcDirs 'src\\main\\assets'
        }
    }
}
}

 dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.2'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:7.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:3.0.0-RC3'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.7.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

And my XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".user.LoginActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loginText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/welcome_to"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.07999998" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loginText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/zenovic_trust"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginText1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01999998" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loginText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:text="@string/login1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginText2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/emailLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="10dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="10dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:endIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
    app:errorTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginText3"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_email"
    app:startIconTint="@color/colorWhite">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/inputLoginEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/passwordLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:hint="@string/password"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="10dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="10dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
    app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="2dp"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    app:endIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
    app:errorTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailLayout"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_security"
    app:startIconTint="@color/colorWhite">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/inputLoginPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkBox" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSignUp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:text="@string/don_t_have_an_account_signup_here"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/forgotPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="@string/forgot_password"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLogin" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:buttonTint="@color/colorWhite"
    android:text="@string/stay_logged_in"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/passwordLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordLayout" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can u share your gradle file ??

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo As per your suggestion added my gradle file

Comment: Am getting Render problem error wherever constraint layout used

Comment: can u show your layout file too ??

Comment: and did u tried invalidate cache and restart option in android studio ??

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo tried but not working